# Automated Pay-Days, Genuine Marketing or Scam

Tags: google, ads

For last two days, I have been noting the add on many high traffic websites that reads `Google pays me $5000 per month`
The add looks like the following on stackoverflow.
[image]

When I click on the ad, it takes me to a [page](http://financereports24-7.com/1p/us/) describing the success stories of different people who have benifited from the programs. For registration, I am routed to the [Automated Paydays](http://www.automated-paydays.com/qualified/index.php?mID=686773) website. The website highlights more success stories and offers life time membership for $59 (as on 24-feb-2013). Yesterday, the membership cost was $24.97. When I move on to their [terms and conditions](http://www.automated-paydays.com/terms.php) page, they explicitly disassociate themselves from google, facebook and all other internet giants. This is rather interesting because on their advertimsement, they are using the name of Google which is a credible company and one cannot easily overlook such an offer provided that it is made by google. 
Furthermore, in their earning discalimer section, they state that all the success stories belong to the people with exceptional skills and we don't guarentee that every member can acheive same or similar results.

To sum it all up, there is high level of contradiction present in the content about automatic-paydays. My question is, given all the contradiction, should someone still trust this website? If someone has knowledge or experience with this site please guide. Is this really a genuine marketing company or another scam on the internet?
Regards

Comment: I wouldn't trust it, but this is not a question for this site.

Comment: Isn't it a web application. where would this question belong to?

Comment: No, it's not a web app. Since it looks like malware I'd say [su] would be a better place for it. Note, though, that not every question has a "place" on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never saw a "overlay" ad on a Stack Exchange site that looked like that (overlays the question list, with a close button on the top right).

Besides the fact that the ad itself looks and sounds suspect *(all "earn thousands of dollars for a few hours working from home" ads are suspect, especially when they use the name of a company like Google, but disassociate themselves from Google in their fine print)*, are you sure that you don't have some kind of malware on your machine that displays that ad in your browser?

It certainly doesn't look like the other ads on the Stack Exchange sites, and I'm sure that the guys at Stack Exchange would never sell ad space to someone like this.

Comment: yeah that is an effect of Malware.

Comment: I think, yes. its malware. when I open stackoverflow in FF, there is no ad but in chrome it shows up almost every time. Thanks for sorting that.